# Unmapping Vim Plugin mappings

Tags: vim

Is there a way to unmap mappings set by plugins?  I'm currently calling `exe ":mapclear"` before my custom mappings in my .vimrc file, but the plugin files appear to be sourced after the vimrc file does.  I have to resource my vimrc file again for it to work as expected.

I'm using Pathogen for sourcing plugins, which are all contained in my ~/.vim/bundle folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could write the part with the mappings in your .vimrc in another file, say MyMaps.vim, and put this file in ~/.vim/after/plugin/.
This should make your maps the default ones

Look also at the documentation of the plugins setting the mappings, some of them
allow you redifine or deactivate the default mappings.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds like a cool trick, though it disconnects my configuration from my .vimrc file.

Comment: Regarding the issue of keeping the configuration in one place you can create a function with your mappings and then use an autocommand to call that function each time you enter a buffer: autocmd BufEnter * call MyMaps(). This would allow you to keep the configuration in your .vimrc file. I don't know about setting a second mapleader.

Answer (score -1):

While snooping around my various plugins, I've found a kind of solution.

Unfortunately, a lot of the plugins (such as vim-surround, and vim-align, which in turn uses cecutil) add commands to my mapleader.  Since I realised there actually are some key mappings from plugins I do use, I decided to set my mapleader back to its default (backslash) at the end of my vimrc file to prevent overlap.

The only problem I came across were mappings that were set in functions.  When using `au FileType html call ConfigHTML()`, for example, the `ConfigHTML()` function would actually get called after the mapleader is set back to backslash.

Comment: What is your solution?